# Getting error while execution through universal g code sender

Tags: iot, arduino-uno

I am trying to create a CNC machine and using GRBL 0.9i Firmware and universal g code sender. after creating the gcode in inkspace and sending the gcode to machine

[image],

I am getting error as following

> An error was detected while sending 'M18': error: Unsupported command. Streaming has been paused.
>
> **** Pausing file transfer. ****"

I am quite new to this and any help would be wonderful and greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jaideep

Answer (score 0):

GRBL does not support M18 (Spindle Orient) so you will need to remove all `M18`s from your program before running it. If you you can't prevent inkspace (I'm not familiar with it) from using that code you might have to use a text editor to replace all `M18`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jimber for your reply. will try and let you know.